# How to add a class to entityform inputs

Tags: drupal-7, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an entityform block and I want to add bootstrap classes to its input!
How can I do this and what files should I edit?

I'm using latest version of entityform and entity block on drupal.org

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add these functions to your template.php file inside your theme folder (replace THEME_NAME with the actual name of your theme):

```
function THEME_NAME_textfield($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'text';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'value', 'size', 'maxlength'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-text'));

  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-control';

  $extra = '';
  if ($element['#autocomplete_path'] && drupal_valid_path($element['#autocomplete_path'])) {
    drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.autocomplete');
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-autocomplete';

    $attributes = array();
    $attributes['type'] = 'hidden';
    $attributes['id'] = $element['#attributes']['id'] . '-autocomplete';
    $attributes['value'] = url($element['#autocomplete_path'], array('absolute' => TRUE));
    $attributes['disabled'] = 'disabled';
    $attributes['class'][] = 'autocomplete';
    $extra = '<input' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
  }

  $output = "<div class='input-wrapper'>";
  $output .= '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
  $output .= "</div>";
  return $output . $extra;
}


function THEME_NAME_button($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'submit';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'value'));

  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-' . $element['#button_type'];
  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'btn btn-default';
  if (!empty($element['#attributes']['disabled'])) {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-button-disabled';
  }
  $value = $element['#attributes']["value"];
  if( isset($element['#attributes']["button-type"]) && $element['#attributes']["button-type"] == "search" ) {
    $value = $element['#attributes']["icon"];
    unset($element['#attributes']["icon"]);
  }  
  return '<button' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $value . '</button>';
}


function THEME_NAME_select($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'size'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-select', 'form-control'));

  return '<select' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . form_select_options($element) . '</select>';
}
```

These functions will add the classes you need for the button, textfield and select input types. Also you will need to include the bootstrap files in your theme.